# error on mysqli multiple connection via class

Tags: php, mysqli

i have the following problem which costs me the last couple of hours...

i have a class for mysqli connections:

```
class database extends SplObjectStorage{

  private $db_link;


  public function __construct($MySQLi_DB){
     if(!file_exists($_SERVER["HOME"].'/'.(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1, strpos(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1),'/'))).'/includes/mysqli.inc.php')){
        echo "MySQLi Include Datei nicht vorhanden";
     }else{
        if (!$this->create_connection($MySQLi_DB) == true){
            echo "Error creating Database. Parameter '".$MySQLi_DB."' unknown<br><br>";
        }           
     }
  }

  public function query($query){
     Return $this->db_link->query($query);
  }


  public function close(){
     mysqli_close($this->db_link);
  } 


 private function create_connection($MySQLi_DB){

    include_once($_SERVER["HOME"].'/'.(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1, strpos(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1),'/'))).'/includes/mysqli.inc.php');
    $this->db_link = new mysqli($MySQLi_Host, $MySQLi_User, $MySQLi_Passw, $MySQLi_Praefix.$MySQLi_DB);
    $this->attach($this->db_link);  

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQLi: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

    echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";     
}
```

The constructor initializes the class by looking for an include-file which contains all connectiondata like user, pwd, etc.

it although receive a parameter ($MySQLi_DB) which is similar to the databasename.

When i call this class with this command:

`$SSO_DB = new database('SSO');`

This class works fine.
Changing the parameter do another databasename is no problem.
e.g.: `$Social_DB   = new database('social');`

This is even no problem until i call two instanzes of my class on the same page!

e.g.:

```
$SSO_DB         = new database('SSO');
$Social_DB  = new database('social');
```

Returns this error: 
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'social' in /volume1/web/portal/classes/database.class.php on line 41

Line 41 is:

```
$this->db_link = new mysqli($MySQLi_Host, $MySQLi_User, $MySQLi_Passw, $MySQLi_Praefix.$MySQLi_DB);
```

When i remove one of the classcalls no error.
No matter which call i remove...

Any idea?

Comment: Where do you define `$MySQLi_Host, $MySQLi_User, $MySQLi_Passw, $MySQLi_Praefix`the error states that user '' (empty) doesn't have access to DB social. So my guess is they're undefined. You need to setup a user that has access to both `SSO` and `social` DBs

Comment: They are defined in:
 include_once($_SERVER["HOME"].'/'.(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1, strpos(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1),'/'))).'/includes/mysqli.inc.php');

for testing purposes i use root. this user has grant on all databases.
Beside this: connection works fine, until i call the class twice on the same page.

Comment: try `var_dump()`'ing them, because at least User is empty (according to the error).

Comment: changing include_once() into include() solved the problem!
php seems to store how often the class is called on one page and did not included the file a second time. thanks Eduardo !!!

Answer (score 0):

changing include_once() into include() solved the problem! php seems to store how often the class is called on one page and did not included the file a second time.